# Array skips the numeric index when adding element?

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've faced funny bug when modifying the e-store engine:

```
// ...

$this->toolbar_title[] = 'Products';

// ...

print_r($this->toolbar_title);
/*
Array (
    [0] => Products 
)
*/

$this->toolbar_title[] = 'Filtered by: name';
print_r($this->toolbar_title);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Products
    [2] => Filtered by: name
)
*/
// ...
```

wat??? where is the "1" index??
Tried to reproduce this in clean stand-alone php script - nope! the added element has index "1" as expected. but when doing the same within the engine code - new element has index "2".

There are no setters, no "[]" overloading found, even no any access to the $this->toolbar_title elements by index, only pushing via [];

What the magic is this? What and where should I seek to find the reason?
PHP 5.6, PrestaShop 1.6 engine.

Thanks a lot in advance for any clue.

UPD: the exact code fragment from engine

```
        if ($filter = $this->addFiltersToBreadcrumbs()) {
            echo'131-';print_r($this->toolbar_title);
            $this->toolbar_title[] = $filter;
            echo'132-';var_dump($this->toolbar_title);
        }
```

where addFiltersToBreadcrumbs returns the string and make NO any access to toolbar_title

UPD2:

```
public function addFiltersToBreadcrumbs()
{
    if ($this->filter && is_array($this->fields_list)) {
        $filters = array();

        foreach ($this->fields_list as $field => $t) {
            if (isset($t['filter_key'])) {
                $field = $t['filter_key'];
            }

            if (($val = Tools::getValue($this->table.'Filter_'.$field)) || $val = $this->context->cookie->{$this->getCookieFilterPrefix().$this->table.'Filter_'.$field}) {
                if (!is_array($val)) {
                    $filter_value = '';
                    if (isset($t['type']) && $t['type'] == 'bool') {
                        $filter_value = ((bool)$val) ? $this->l('yes') : $this->l('no');
                    } elseif (isset($t['type']) && $t['type'] == 'date' || isset($t['type']) && $t['type'] == 'datetime') {
                        $date = Tools::unSerialize($val);
                        if (isset($date[0])) {
                            $filter_value = $date[0];
                            if (isset($date[1]) && !empty($date[1])) {
                                $filter_value .= ' - '.$date[1];
                            }
                        }
                    } elseif (is_string($val)) {
                        $filter_value = htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    }
                    if (!empty($filter_value)) {
                        $filters[] = sprintf($this->l('%s: %s'), $t['title'], $filter_value);
                    }
                } else {
                    $filter_value = '';
                    foreach ($val as $v) {
                        if (is_string($v) && !empty($v)) {
                            $filter_value .= ' - '.htmlspecialchars($v, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                        }
                    }
                    $filter_value = ltrim($filter_value, ' -');
                    if (!empty($filter_value)) {
                        $filters[] = sprintf($this->l('%s: %s'), $t['title'], $filter_value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($filters)) {
            return sprintf($this->l('filter by %s'), implode(', ', $filters));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine https://3v4l.org/i6sEc, which means - you show us __not all__ related code.

Comment: of cause I cant post all the engine code :)  And I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I really cant imagine what it could be? The question is - what should I check to discover this bug? Any ideas, even totaly insane ;)

Comment: Just to be sure, you are executing this code as shown, there is absolutely nothing else in between, yes?

Comment: I've edited a little the example. Now the "..." means "something here", and if there are NO "..." - it means - absolutely nothing here. I mean, there is definetely nothing else between two debug "print_r" calls but posted above.

Comment: ... modified a little more - added the exact code fragment

Comment: It doesn't matter what `addFiltersToBreadcrumbs` returns. More important what it does inside.

Comment: OK, I've added full addFiltersToBreadcrumbs code

Comment: Example https://3v4l.org/tdhfl - so find similar behaviour. As `toolbar_title` is not used in `addFiltersToBreadcrumbs` - `unset` happens __earlier__

Comment: "unset" was the first that I've tried to find, but there are no any unset calls to toolbar_title found.

Comment: wait... *earlier* unset is what I've missed... thanks for now, will check for this.

Comment: Aarh, got it, Not **unset**, but **array_unique** was the reason! Thanks a lot for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

For php, if you unset one index in array, the index will appear discontinuous growth.

```php
$this->toolbar_title = array_values($this->toolbar_title);
```

will rebuild the index.